# How to get an array inside group of arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have an array from php and here it is

```
$results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1,
        "iTotalRecords" => count($newdata),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($newdata),
        "aaData" => $newdata
);

echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

all of the data is also packed as array inside `aaData` my question here is how can I get that data? my target is to populate that in a table and here is my code.

```
<script>
        var i,x;
        var tb = $("#col_details");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'qry_collection.php',
                type: "POST",
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                /* Delete table content */
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                $("#col_details tr").remove();
                /* Populate the table */
                   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       var tr = $("<tr />");
                       for (x in data[i]) {
                            var td = $("<td />");
                            td.html(data[i][x]);
                            tr.append(td);
                            count = i 
                        }
                        tb.append(tr);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I can see the array using the console but populating it as table is my prob.

TYSM

here is the image from console

[image]

Comment: You can't 'get' a PHP variable from AJAX; you'd need to build the table whilst passing in the data on the PHP side.

Comment: what do you mean? create the table in the php already? I think I can get the data because it shows on console.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint inside the array or object loop, can you step through and see if it's constructing the cells and rows as expected?

Comment: What I mean is that you can't access the `$results` variable from an AJAX POST. You'd need to `echo` out `$results` on `qry_collection.php`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge please see my updated post

Comment: @stealththeninja what do you mean sir? please check I add an image of the output. those this one satisfied your needs?

Comment: iterate over the array **data.aaData** and build table , or maybe make the table html ready in php part first ..

Comment: @jirarium how to loop over it?

Comment: Something like :         `for (var i=0; i<data.aaData.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.aaData[i]);
            
        }`

Comment: its working now TYSM :D

Comment: @NardongBagsik , yw ; )

Comment: @jirarium one more is it possible to create a `<td>` for that and put it inside `<tbody>`?

Comment: @NardongBagsik yes , just like in your code sample , you can do whatever you want with the array elements .

Comment: @jirarium ty so so so so so so much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with properties of `sEcho, iTotalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords, aaData`. You want to iterate over `data.aaData` which an array of whatever `$newdata` is.

---

EDIT:

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    /* Delete table content */
    $("#col_details tr").remove();
    /* Populate the table */
    $("#col_details").html(data.reduce((out, tr) => `${out}<tr>${d.reduce((o, td) => `<td>${td}</td>`, '')}</tr>`, ''));
}
```

---

@Aloso pointed out that this is likely to be run straight in a browser, so your probably don't want to use template strings.

In that case you switch up the formatting a little:

```
function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    /* Delete table content */
    $("#col_details tr").remove();
    /* Populate the table */
    $("#col_details").html(data.reduce(function(out, tr) { return out + '<tr>' + d.reduce(function(o, td) { return '<td>' + td + '</td>'}, '')} + '</tr>'}, ''));
}
```

Comment: yes sir is it possible to get it over and put it inside a table?

Comment: and by the the $newdata is an output of a query

Comment: @NardongBagsik try updating your outer loop to iterate over `data.aaData`, not `data` because it's an object. Aside: not every community member here is a "sir".

Comment: Yes. I don't know what each of your elements is, but what you have there will at least sort of work, you are just iterating over the wrong thing in your outer loop.

`for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {` should be `for (i = 0; i < data.aaData.length; i++) {`

Comment: @stealththeninja noted and sorry for the wrong call

Comment: @MarkCooper try to change it but it gives me an error of `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: You shouldn't use template strings since they still don't work in every browser, e.g. Internet Explorer 11 and some mobile browsers

Comment: @Aloso That's true. I will amend my answer to make that clear.